# Scipy LinearOperator on a matrix

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a linear function `A` that whose input and output is `(m,n)`numpy array. I want to use CG or GMRES to solve a system `A(x) = b`. Is there any way I can define scipy `LinearOperator` without reshaping the input and output inside my function `A`?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg as linalg

a = np.array( [ [1,2] , [3,4] ] )
def A(v):
    return a * v

# I want to do this but this fails. Any other
# solution that doesn't involve reshaping?
lin_op = linalg.LinearOperator( ((2,2),(2,2)), matvec=A )
```

Comment: LinearOperator is described as `Common interface for performing matrix vector products` in the docstring - so it seems that it is not intended for matrix-matrix products

Comment: @cel First - for whoever reads this - you can implement a matrix-matrix product via the 'matmat' argument. See documentation. Second - I was hoping there would be a natural (read - easy / hassle free ) way of viewing matrices as vectors (since matrices of given dimensions do form a vector space).

Comment: `ravel` writes a matrix as a vector but like reshaping. Have you tried `numpy einsum`? This may be a way to specify exactly the form you want